# Block GraphQL Playground access by ip

Tags: graphql

I'd like to block the access to the GraphQL playground of my API. Basically what I wanna do is make the playground accessible only for a certain IP range and if someone tries to access it and it's out of that range throw a 404 error. Is it possible to do that? How could I do that?

Comment: Do you use Apollo Server or one of its migrations, e.g. Express?

Comment: @pzaenger I'm using apollo-server-express.